# How to test compiled JAR file using Gradle

Tags: java, testing, gradle, travis-ci

I had a code that was working correctly when was executed during standard unit testing, but didn't work when it was compiled into the jar and was added as dependency for some other project.

It wasn't an issue to find the root cause and fix it, but I started to think how can I test freshly made jar artifact before deploying it anywhere, to make sure that it will work for end users and other projects. I have googled this topic for several hours, but didn't even find something close to it.

Maybe I'm totally wrong and trying to achieve something weird, but I cannot figure out another way how to verify compiled packages and be confident that it will work for others.

Some details about the project - simple Java library with few classes, using Gradle 5.5 as a build system and travis-ci as CI/CD tool, for testing I'm using TestNG, but I can easily switch to JUnit if it will be required.

If you curious about the code, which was not working when was compiled into the package, here is simplified version:

```java
public String readResourceByURI() throws IOException, URISyntaxException
{
  new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("resource.txt").toURI())));
}
```

This function will throw java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException if packaged into the jar file. But as I said the problem is not with the code...

Ideally, I want to create a build pipeline, that will produce jar artifacts, which then will be tested and if tests are successful those jars will be automatically deployed to repository (maven and/or bintray).

At the moment all tests are executed before jar creation and as a result there is chance, that compiled code inside jar package will not work due to packaging.

So, to simplify my question I'm looking for a Gradle configuration that can execute unit tests on a freshly made jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what I came up with:

```
test {

    // Add dependency on jar task, since it will be main target for testing
    dependsOn jar

    // Rearrange test classpath, add compiled JAR instead of main classes
    classpath = project.sourceSets.test.output + configurations.testRuntimeClasspath + files(jar.archiveFile)

    useTestNG()
}
```

Here I'm changing default classpath for test task by combining folder with test classes, runtime dependencies and compiled JAR file. Not sure if it's correct way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

In Gradle you can try to execute some scripting task that run code from your jar. Or complex but on simple POC it works.
In main gradle project create subproject 'child'.
Add inforation about it in settings.gradle:

```
include 'child'
```

In build.gradle add this:

```
task externalTest {
    copy {
        from 'src/test'
        into './child/src/test'
    }
}
externalTest.dependsOn(':child:build')

jar.doLast {
    externalTest
}
```

And in child/settings.gradle in dependency add parent jar:

```
compile files('../build/libs/parent.jar')
```

Now in main project on build, the child project will be build after jar creation.

Comment: My JAR file is not executable so it will not run this way. I just want to execute unit tests against compiled jar.

Comment: Maybe try tu run this test in another gradle project that has as dependency your jar. In this way you must have another collection of test.

Comment: Yes, this definitely can be done, however it's quite complex to maintain - for every project like this you need to create additional Gradle project and most probably link them together. And also where do I need to keep all my testing code? In this separate project? Anyway, this will be my last resort approach if I won't find something easier. I'm pretty sure it can be implemented way easier in Gradle, just cannot figure it out

Comment: Yes, it would be complex. You could create sub project. After build your main jar you can copy it as dependency to subproject. The same with test code. After that run the build in subproject.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a good way to detect this kind of problem in a unit test.  It is the kind of problem that is normally found in an integration test.

If your artifact / deliverable is a library, integration tests don't normally make a lot of sense.  However, you *could* spend some time to create a sample or test application that uses your library, which you can then write an integration test for.

You would need to ask yourself whether there are enough potential errors of this kind to warrant doing that:

- I don't image that you will make this particular mistake again soon.
- Other problems of this nature might include assumptions in your library about the OS platform or (occasionally) Java versions ... which can only really be tested by running an application on the different platforms.

Maybe the pragmatic answer is to recognize that you cannot (or cannot afford to) test everything.

---

Having said that, one possible approach might be to chose a free-standing test runner (packaged as a non-GUI Java application).  Then get Gradle to run the test runner as a scripted task with JARs for your library and the unit tests on the classpath.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! Actually your second point about OS platform and/or java versions is exactly why I want to implement such pipeline - CI/CD tools allow us to automate testing on different platforms and versions and it's quite logical to automate also testing of deliverables to protect from potential issues that can happen due to packaging.

Comment: Creating a sample application, which will use my library is one way to go, but I'm curios can it be done much simplier than this? Gradle is very powerful tool, I just can not believe that it's not possible to play somehow with classpathes and inject compiled JAR as a dependency for unit tests...

Comment: See my last paragraph.  But I have my doubts that you can get enough extra "coverage" to make it worthwhile to run unit tests out of a JAR.  (That only really deals with this specific problem with resource loading.)

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot agree with you. I don't think that problem with resource loading is the only problem that can happen due to packaging, I can easily imagine issues with some dependencies, which can be missing in the jar, but exist in your classpath during development and test execution. And one more thing is that I want to make this pipeline a default one for my future projects, and since such errors can happen at the beginning of the project I'm ready to invest some time now to avoid it in the future.

Comment: It will be the same gradle configs that determine the dependencies in all of your test / dev environments. I don't think running the tests a second time would detect missing dependencies ... beyond what the CI server already does.

Comment: Why running tests two times? My idea is to run one iteration of tests, the only exception is that it can be executed against jar file instead of compiled .class files.

Comment: Well .... one iteration of the tests the normal way, and a second iteration the special way.  That's two.  Or did you intend to NOT run the tests the normal way?  But either way, I have my doubts that you would find anything other than the specific problem you have already identified.

Comment: Yes, I intended not to run tests the "normal" way, but run it against the jar file. It will give me the same coverage as before + confidence that jar deliverable will not fail for others. Even if this specific problem is the only issue that can happen, I still want to protect from it, because a) I can forget about it b) somebody else who is not familiar with this problem can do it.